# How to manipulate datetime objects with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am relatively new to python and my work requires me to write a script to classify customers into Tiers.

This is the logic I need to implement:

> Tier Level Qualifications :
> Account Travel spend will now be tracked on a 12 month-rolling cycle granting customers instant qualification to the Tier Level and benefits as it is reached.
> As a Tier level is reached it will be secured for a 12-month period.
> If a higher Tier level is reached, the account will be instantly upgraded to the higher level for a 12 month period.
> If the account’s travel spend drops within the 12-month period, the account maintains the Tier level until the expiry date.
> Account will be reassessed at end of the 12month period fornew qualifying status.
> Revenue calculation is calculated on a day by day basis with a 7-day delay.

I am using SQLAlchemy to pull data from our database and pandas to format it as a dataframe. I filtered the dataframe to display transaction of one customer only.
I then used the pandas rolling function to calculate the 12-months rolling sum.

At this point, the dataframe looks like this:

```
                 tot_rev_base    rolling
    DATE                         
    2022-08-21           0.00  139558.47
    2022-08-22           0.00  139558.47
    2022-08-23        3902.93  140314.65
    2022-08-24         467.60  138790.25
    2022-08-25           0.00  138235.25
    2022-08-26        1265.10  135559.90
    2022-08-27           0.00  134676.00
    2022-08-28           0.00  134676.00
    2022-08-29           0.00  134676.00
    2022-08-30         664.25  134935.70
    2022-08-31        1712.40  132872.30
    2022-09-01         458.70  131291.50
    2022-09-02         802.00  131305.75
    2022-09-03           0.00  131305.75
    2022-09-04           0.00  128518.30
    2022-09-05           0.00  128518.30
    2022-09-06           0.00  128518.30
    2022-09-07         655.70  128626.60
    2022-09-08        1238.25  129864.85
```

I have written a simple iteration to add a column with a Tier level depending on the rolling sum of that day, where "row" contains the date as index, revenue and rolling sum:

```py
def Tiers(row):
    
    date = row[0]
    revenue = row[1][0]
    rolling = row[1][1]

    if rolling < 10000:
        df3.loc[date,'tier'] = 0

    elif rolling < 150000:
        df3.loc[date,'tier'] = 1

    elif rolling < 300000:
        df3.loc[date,'tier'] = 2

    elif rolling < 500000:
        df3.loc[date,'tier'] = 3
        
    elif rolling > 500000:
        df3.loc[date,'tier'] = 4
```

So far, so good. The issue I am having is to implement the "As a Tier level reached it will be secured for a 12-month period. If a higher Tier level is reached, the account will be instantly upgraded to the higher level for a 12-month period. If the account’s travel spend drops within the 12-month period, the account maintains the Tier level until the expiry date. "

Comment: maybe add a column `date_tier_reached` and a `days_since_reaching_tier` and work from there

Comment: for your Tiers function, take a look at [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to apply your tier for numbers in the different ranges. Related to your question: for me that sounds for a good use of [`pd.cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html)  maybe?

Comment: in your `Tiers` def'n, what is `df3`? Is it a global?

Comment: yes. df3 is the dataframe from the snapshot above

Comment: Are you able to provide a (sanitised?) [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The example dataframe you provide seems to have the customer in tier 1 on all days.